# How to crawl webpages with titles in URL?

Tags: python, url, request, web-crawler, urllib

I would like to crawl news from a webpage. They use URLs like this:
https://www.eqs-news.com/de/news/adhoc/vectron-systems-ag-vectron-uebernimmt-acardo/1724329

The last number in the URL is a unique news ID. My hope was that I would be able to crawl all news by simply looping through all possible IDs. However, that is not possible (at least for me), due to the news title in the URL. Is there any way to circumvent the title in the URL?

Thank you very much in advance!

I tried the following:

- Using the query string https://www.eqs-news.com/?data-news-item=1724329, without success
- I had a look in the sitemap of the webpage but could not find relevant information (https://www.eqs-news.com/wp-sitemap.xml)

Comment: Use a regex, looking for last '/'  and then grabbing all numbers

Comment: Hi pierpy, thank you very much for your hint. However I think it won't help, since my goal is to scrape all news using increasing IDs. In other words, I like to get the URL given the ID. Your solution proposes a way to get the ID given the URL, which is the other way around.

Comment: you are right, ok. So the problem is the absence of a list of categories to loop?

Comment: Exactly. The website changed its domain. Prior to the change, I was able to scrape the news from the example above with the following URL: https://www.dgap.de/?newsID=1724329. This style made it easy to scrape all the news by just looping through IDs. My question is whether this is still possible? I.e., is there a way to circumvent the newly introduced title in the URL?

Comment: On homepage, in "advanced filter setting" there is a <div> that seems to contain macro-categories:  the XPath is: `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div`

Comment: Hi pierpy. Again, thank you very much for your help, I highly appreciate that. Your are right, with your Xpath I am able to extract these marco-categories, which are in my case the news types. However, I think this does not solve my problem? Again, the title in the URL is my problem. In the example above, this is "vectron-systems-ag-vectron-uebernimmt-acardo". Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to scrape `...acardo/1' , `...acardo/2` and so on? It seems that I don't fully understand problem to solve :-D

Comment: No. As I said, the domain changed. Before the change, I was able to crawl all news with a loop, like that (simplified):

for id in range(0,1.000.000):
     response = request.urlopen('https://www.dgap.de/?newsID=id
                    
However, after the change this is not possible anymore since the title of the respective news appears in the URL, like in my example. The only point of my question is whether it is possible to do some trick on the URL (like some query string) to get the HTML file of the news without the need of the title.